Is there any way to easily populate values in Excel for testdata preparation?
The application I am testing has an upload excel functionality. This Excel has around 8 sheets, where the values we input have some dependencies.
Currently, we are manually inputting the values in Excel to prepare testdata.
Is there any other way which can be used for populating the values in the Excel Sheets?
I think parameterization using test automation requires equal effort as manual.

Post few sample data what you want to generate. Also explain logic to generate those data. SEQUENCE(), RANDBETWEEN() these functions can generate data automatically.

Here is the sample of generated test data:

Formulas:
[A2] =SEQUENCE(10)
[B2] =CHAR(SEQUENCE(10,,65))
[C2] =MAP(SEQUENCE(10),LAMBDA(I,TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,CHAR(RANDARRAY(5,,65,90,TRUE)))))
[D2] =RANDARRAY(10,,0,100,TRUE)
[E2] =RANDARRAY(10,,15,25,FALSE)
[F2] =RANDARRAY(10,,45560,45700,TRUE); cell format "dd.mm.yyyy"
[G2] =RANDARRAY(10,,0,1,FALSE); cell format "h:mm:ss"
[H2] =RANDARRAY(10,,45560,45700,FALSE); cell format "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm"

If you need combinations of sequences like {A1,A2,..A10,B1,B2..}:
=TOCOL(CHAR(SEQUENCE(10,,65))&SEQUENCE(1,10))

